# How to get seo friendly article url in joomla without assiging it to any menu

Tags: php, url, joomla

I am a wordpress developer and new for Joomla cms. Currently i am working on a Joomla project.
I have created articles from admin section and i want to call those articles in my front end with seo friendly url(`http://www.example.com/article-alias`) without assigning it any menu.

I am already using url like this `/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=article_id` to get article in front end.

Thanks in advance for any suggestion or solution.

Comment: if you turn on the SEO Settings in site setting your urls will be more SEO friendly , you will get : /categoryid-categoryname/articleid-articename
also there is some free SEO components , that will remove id from url too
joomla is MVC based cms , you cant have that unclear urls in wordpress here , except with magic of menu in joomla

Answer (score 1):

In my Joomla instance I created a new menu called "blank" to put any articles I wanted to link to directly instead of adding them to the navigation on the site. I assigned my articles to that menu, and there is a field called "alias", manually type in the name you want to appear in your URL (like `article-alias`). Then you can link directly to that page with `example.com/article-alias`. This will also allow you to add modules to the page from the module manager and selecting your articles from the "blank" menu.

Comment: thanks @Robert for your solution. But as i mentioned in my question does any way to direct call articles without assigning to any menu?

Comment: I've seen that the JCE extension (http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/extension/edition/editors/jce) can create links to articles bypassing the menu system, but I haven't tried that. From my Joomla experience, it is much cleaner to create a hidden menu to control your alias.